# Populating Google Maps with Markers from C# List

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying to populate a javascript google map with a c# list of google map markers. I can get data in from public floats but not from the list. The list will be populated by the database but in this case the list is hard coded. I have one hard coded marker added in. Any Ideas?

ASP.NET Web Form

```
<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function InitialiseMap() {

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng('<%= lat %>', '<%= lng %>');
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 9,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

        Placement(a, 1, 1);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Test!'
        });
    }

    //window.onload = InitialiseMap();
</script>
```

C#

public class Placement
    {
        public string PlacementName { get; set; }
        public float Latitude { get; set; }
        public float Longitude { get; set; }

```
    public List<Placement> GetPlacementDetails()
    {
        Placement placement = new Placement();
        placement.PlacementName = "Placement 1";
        placement.Latitude = 53.28097170166426F;
        placement.Longitude = -2.9433422088622F;

        Placement placement2 = new Placement();
        placement2.PlacementName = "Placement 2";
        placement2.Latitude = 55.74326998205062F;
        placement2.Longitude = -2.8699998855590F;

        List<Placement> placements = new List<Placement>();

        placements.Add(placement);
        placements.Add(placement2);

        return placements;
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if you are using `.net web forms`, but if you are, you could use `[WebMethod]` in your `aspx.cs`-file to create something like a webservice. When you then ask in your request for `content-type: application/json` it'll be automatically serialized to JSON. More information here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/static-webmethod-in-code-behind-webform/

Comment: Have you tried any of the .net API's for google maps?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a service to access the data

[How to create a web service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37727/Prepare-a-JSON-Web-Service-and-access-it-with-JQue)